# Exposing a vector of shared_pointers without giving ownership

Tags: c++, vector, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I have a simple class containing a vector of shared pointers:

```
class Bar {
public:
  /* stuff */
private:
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Foo>> foos;
};
```

I wish to expose my `foos` through a `getFoos()` function, that would not share the ownership of the objects. One way to do so would be:

```
std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<Foo>> Bar::getFoos() const {
  std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<Foo>> fooRefs;
  fooRefs.reserve(foos.size());
  for (auto& ptr : foos) {
    fooRefs.push_back(std::ref(*ptr));
  }
  return fooRefs;
}
```

but that's pretty ugly. Also, I'll most likely need to cache the results since this function gets called pretty often. More complexity, more ugliness.

Is there a cleaner/better way to deal with this issue?

Comment: Why not `const std::vector<std::shared_pointer<Foo>>& getFoos() const { return foos; }`? At this point, this is not yet shared ownership but just a const reference to the original.

Comment: maybe your can provide a method named `Foo& getFoo(std::size_t index);` and expose Foo through that?.

Comment: what about a `std::vector<std::weak_ptr<Foo>> getFoos()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would expose the `Foo` by index and also give the possibility to obtain iterators to them

```cpp
class Bar {
public:
  class FooIt {
    // Add typedefs for category etc
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Foo>>::iterator it; // maybe template on this to easily provide the const overload too
  public:
    Foo& operator*() const {
      return **it;
    }
    // write Functions to expose ++ etc of it
  };

  FooIt begin() {
    return FooIt{begin(foos)};
  }

  FooIt end() { 
    retuen FooIt{end(foos)};
  }
  // Enables ranged for over Bar, only do if that makes sense for your Bar

  Foo& getFoo(size_t index) { // maybe even operator [] if appropriate
    return foos[index];
  }
};
```

Of course this is much boilerplate. But actually you can write the `FooIt` in a general, templated version if you have this problem at multiple places.

Comment: I like this solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly a range view with [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3):

```
class Bar {
public:
  /* stuff */

     auto get_foos() const { return foos | ranges::views::indirect; }
private:
  std::vector<std::shared_pointer<Foo>> foos;
};
```

Similar to your `std::vector<reference_wrapper>`, but without extra vector.

> `views::indirect`
>       Given a source range of readable values (e.g. pointers or iterators), return a new view that is the result of dereferencing each.

Can also be done with `view::transform`.

Comment: range-v3 is available for C++14 too.